# How to configure jolokia to get metrics from a hadoop node/cluster

Tags: hadoop, jolokia

I have been trying to configure jolokia to get jvm metrics from a hadoop node using the jolokia agent  so i can forward them , to elastic search using metric beat , but its not working.

I downloaded the jolokia agent and specified it as -javaagent with the port and the agent path specified in the hadoop-env.sh file under export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS= and  export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS, but its not working and the port is not listening.

Can anyone help with this or has experience configuring jolokia

Comment: I assume you mean "in" not "under" those values? Use `ps` and look at the running processes. Is the agent actually added / are those values used? Also, why Jolokia/Elasticsearch over Prometheus + JMX Exporter / Grafana?

Comment: yes i meant in , i cant find the agent when i used ps and i'm using jolokia because i couldnt configure jmx exporter

Comment: They're both configured very similarly. Please show the exact configuration you've added and tried. As mentioned, arguments don't go "under" those exports as a new line in the file. Have you restarted the processes after editing the hadoop-env file? What commands are you running to start them? You'll also need to modify every node in the cluster, assuming you're not running everything on one machine

Comment: You might find this post useful https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/monitor-infrastructure/integrations/integration-reference/integration-apache-hadoop/